# Django html IF statement not comparing model variables

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Trying to nest an IF statement in FOR loops to segment videos by a parent variable. However, my if statement doesn't seem to be recognising matches.

I can confirm that both output some matching numbers in their respective statements individually.
Not sure what I'm missing here, any help would be appreciated.

**Profile.html**

```
{% for x in source %}
    <div class="content-section">
      <div class="media-body">
      <h2 class="account-heading">{{ x.video_id }}</h2>
      {% for y in records %}
        <h1 class="text-secondary">{{ y.sourcevideo.video_id }}</h1>
        {% if '{{ x.video_id }}' == '{{ y.sourcevideo.video_id }}' %}
          <video width="320" height="240" controls>
            <source src="{{ y.highlight }}" type="video/mp4">
              Your browser does not support the video tag
            </video>
        {% else %}
        <h1 class="text-secondary">No Matches</h1>
        {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
      </div>
    </div>
  {% endfor %}
```

**views.py**

```
class ProfileView(ListView):
    model = Highlight
    template_name = 'users/profile.html'
    context_object_name = 'records'
    ordering = ['-date_created']

    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Highlight.objects.filter(creator=self.request.user)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['source'] = Video.objects.filter(creator=self.request.user)
        return context
```

Comment: you can't use templating variables inside the if statement, it should be just python code: `{% if x.video_id == y.sourcevideo.video_id %}`. your current statement just compares the two string '{{ x.video_id }}' and '{{ y.sourcevideo.video_id }}' which are clearly not the same.

Comment: Solved! Makes sense, thanks!

Comment: [doing the tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial03/#use-the-template-system) or [reading the relevant part of the doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/templates/#tags) would have answered your question FWIW.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your statement is comparing two different strings: `"{{ x.video_id }}"` and `"{{ y.videosource.video_id }}"`.

You need to compare the variables: `{% if x.video_id == y.sourcevideo.video_id %}`.